# Can a website see how you got to the site - by what search term or the last website you were on?

Tags: internet

According to [this article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-22853432), you can glean IP address, type of machine, and screen size when someone visits your site:

> When you visit a website, your IP address, type of machine and screen
>   size can easily be ascertained.
>
> The website can also see how you got to the site - by what search term
>   or the last website you were on. Your location can be found by
>   cross-referring your IP address with other data.

I agree with all of these points apart from

> The website can also see how you got to the site - by what search term
>   or the last website you were on.

As a web developer, I would have said that's impossible. Is that naive journalism or is it somehow possible to find out how a visitor reached your site, what search term they used or the last website they were on?

If you're utilizing Google Analytics you can see what search terms are being used, but it is impossible to associate these search terms with IP addresses.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. See [RFC 7231 (The Hypertext Transfer Protocol) Section 5.5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.2)

> The "Referer" [sic] header field allows the user agent to specify a
> URI reference for the resource from which the target URI was obtained

You can access this value via JavaScript using the [`document.referer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer)  property.

If you follow [this link to w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp), it demonstrates the use of that property to show you that you came from skeptics.stackexchange.com.

However, if you switch to the [https version](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/26694/can-a-website-see-how-you-got-to-the-site-by-what-search-term-or-the-last-webs/26695#26695) of this question, following that link to w3schools will not reveal this site as the referrer. That behavior is part of the standard:

> A user agent MUST NOT send a Referer header field in an
> unsecured HTTP request if the referring page was received with a
> secure protocol.

Comment: I once saw that all Google traffic doesn't leak referers anymore because of Ssl. Can't find the link right now.

Comment: That is correct! That is part of the standard. My most recent edit mentions that.

Comment: The https version redirects me back to the http version.